# Check Whether Rows were Deleted from Table (MySql and Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am was thinking that if I have a query like the following:

```
connection.query("DELETE FROM uln;", function(err, result);
```

That I would be able to check whether any rows were actually deleted using:

```
if(result.changedRows === 0){

   do something..
}
```

However, this does not seem to works as I had expected. Does anyone know how I can check for the condition that no rows were deleted? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `result.changedRows` try using [`result.affectedRows`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#getting-the-number-of-affected-rows) instead. This will provide accurate results for a `DELETE` query.

Comment: Thank you. Using result.affectedRows() after a delete query was what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is result.changedRows not result.changedRows()

Comment: Thanks @MusaHaidari answer is updated to reflect that these are properties, not methods

Answer (score 0):

result.affectedRows() after a delete query will notify accurately number of rows affected.

Comment: Hi. What would have been a better way to reply to this to avoid the -1?

Comment: Well it’s 4 years later but I’d guess it’s because you left the same answer that had been posted days earlier, instead of accepting that answer.